# Dart multiplication

Tags: math, dart

I'm trying to build a calculator app and when i go parse the multiplication `11.2 * 3` the code give me the value `33.599999999999994`.

So I went to check if the same thing happened in dart, and returns exactly that value.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point!

Comment: I saw an example of the [flutter calculator](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/803b15e0db9606f6f4c84925f9c6cb369be72394/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/calculator/logic.dart#L56) on how to handle this.